# execute command working correct but not working post mapping

Tags: vim

The command executed directly works fine. But when it is mapped to some key, it reports syntax errors.

When I execute the below execute command it works as expected

```
:silent execute "normal! ^:s/ ".expand("<cWORD>")." //g\<cr>"
```

But when I  map it to some key say

```
:nnoremap ,g :silent execute "normal! ^:s/ ".expand("<cWORD>")." //g\<cr>"
```

Then when I call the mapping it gives the following error:

```
E114: Missing quote: " //g\
E15: Invalid expression: "normal! ^:s/ ".expand("<cWORD>")." //g\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an escaping issue. The `<cr>` is interpreted literally (the preceding backslash doesn't help here), so Vim doesn't see the final `"` yet and complains about the missing quote. Escaping `<` as `<lt>` is the solution here.

Additionally, you want that `<cr>` interpreted by the `:execute` (it's inside the double quotes and preceded by the backslash), but who's concluding the entire `:execute "...."` now? Another `<cr>` is needed:

```
:nnoremap ,g :silent execute "normal! ^:s/ ".expand("<cWORD>")." //g\<lt>cr>"<cr>
```

However, I think the whole approach is too troublesome; going into Ex mode from `:normal` seldomly is a good idea.

So, you need the `^` to obtain the *first* WORD in the line; you can do that directly, as you start out with normal mode, anyway:

```
:nnoremap ,g ^:execute "s/ ".expand("<cWORD>")." //g"<cr>
```

With this, you just need a single round of interpolation via `:execute`. Looks much better, right?!

Comment: Yess. Looks a lot elegant. Thanks a lot. That was great help.